# Regex Python Buscando datas

Tags: python, regex

```
resultado_limpo = ((busca.find_all(string=re.compile(r'\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'))))
```

estou a tentar a buscar datas no formato dd/mm/aaaa
preciso buscar com ano apenas de 2016 e tem como eu colocar o mês no caso variável
dentro do meu filtro sendo que vou pegar o mês com datetime

Answer (score 1):

```
mes = '07';
ano = '2016';

busca.find_all(string=re.compile("\d{2}\/%s\/%s\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t" % (mes,ano), re.IGNORECASE));
```

Basicamente você gera um string com substituições a serem feitas e compila apos elas ocorrerem.

Answer (score 1):

> Obs: A expressão regular não está validando o formato de data, se
>   quiser a regex pra validar o formato : dd/mm/dddd
>
> [Regex para dd/mm/yyyy](https://github.com/Marlysson/Programacao-Corporativa/tree/master/Uso%20de%20Regex#valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-formato-1)
>
> Mas se quer somente pegar está ok

Para capturar elementos dentro de uma expressão regular usa-se grupos.

[Link de referência](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/grupo.html)

Com eles é possível no retorno da expressão regular armazenar o valor em uma variável da linguagem.

Para definir grupos usa-se o formato:

```
(?P<nome_variavel>regex)
```

Então para a sua regex pegar somente os anos de 2016 e ainda capturando o mês para ser tratado pela linguagem primeiro cria a regex.

```
"\d{2}\/\d{2}\/2016"
```

Depois adiciona-se o grupo que quer capturar..

```
"\d{2}\/(?P<mes>\d{2})\/2016"
```

Depois usa na linguagem:

```
>>> import re
>>> padrao = re.compile("\d{2}\/(?P<mes>\d{2})\/2016")
>>> string_procurada = "Data de hoje: 25/09/2016"
>>> resultado = re.findall(padrao,string)
>>> resultado
['09']
```

Ai depois só fazer os tratamentos necessários : cast para int, adicionar em um lista..

Comment: Muito bom !!!!!

Comment: Marca a resposta que te ajudou :D.